# Qiskit - MultiCX gate mcxgate

Tags: qiskit

I am looking for some help to understand what I am doing wrong.

I am new to QC and I am trying to create circuit that would be in below state -

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{8}}(|000,0\rangle + |001,0\rangle + |010,0\rangle + |011,0\rangle + |100,0\rangle + |101,0\rangle + |110,0\rangle + |111,1\rangle)$$

Below is my code:

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.circuit.library import C4XGate

qc = QuantumCircuit(3+1) # n number of qubits plus one ancilla qubit. 

qc.h(0)
qc.h(1)
qc.h(2)
qc.mct([0, 1, 2], 3, mode="noancilla")
qc.measure_all()

# qc.draw(output="mpl")

from qiskit import Aer, execute, assemble

backend = Aer.get_backend("aer_simulator")
qc.save_statevector()
job = execute(qc, backend, shots=1000)
counts = job.result().get_counts()

print(counts)
```

I am getting below output.

`{'0001': 141, '0010': 120, '0011': 129, '0000': 121, '0101': 122, '1111': 134, '0110': 129, '0100': 104}`

My question is 4th qubit should be 1 when qubit 0, 1 and 2 are 1 (which is true), however, 4th qubit should be 0 otherwise, so why do I have output such as `0001` or `0101`?

Thanks for the help in advanced!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You circuit is correct. The result is not matched with what you expect because Qiskit uses *little endian* bit ordering.

If you want to get the result in *big endian* convention, use [`reverse_bits()`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit.reverse_bits.html) method.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Applying `reverse_bits()` gave me what I was looking for.